# MySQL Rows Based On Prority Values

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a table with four columns: FirstName, LastName, Number (not a primary key) and Status. If a there are a persons with the same First name, Last name and number, but differing status (where status is a string such as "King" or "Queen" or "Jack").

I want to retrieve all the values from the table for all columns, but if there are duplicates where there are those with the same first name, last name, and number, I want to get those with status of "King", and if there a duplicates without the "King" status then get those with "Queen" and if there is no duplicates with "King" or "Queen" than only get one of those with "Jack".

Basically, the order of priority is King, Queen, and then Jack. so, I want all values from the table but if there are duplicates only include the one with the highest priority. I did some research and it appears that SQL implementations other than MYSql provide functions such as dense_rank, but I need to implement this in MYSql and I cannot find any way how.

Comment: update your question add  the code you are using  .. a proper data sample  your actula result and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

One method of doing this involves `union all`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.status = 'King'
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.status = 'Queen' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name andt2.status in ('King'))
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.status = 'Jack' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.status in ('King', 'Queen'));
```

Another method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where (name, field(t.status, 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack')) in
          (select t2.name, max(field(t2.status, 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack'))
           from t t2
           where t2.status in ('King', 'Queen', 'Jack')
           group by t2.name
          );
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I get an error that the subquery returns more than 1 row, and I tried to find out a solution by Googling but I don't see where it would have a problem.

Comment: I fixed the subquery error but using the statement, I do not get any values with "Jack" back, only "King" and "Queen".

Comment: @cjstittles . . . The first method should still work.

Answer (score 0):

try using session variable:

```
SET @row_number:=1;

SELECT
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Number,
    Status
FROM(
    SELECT 
        @row_number:=
        CASE
            WHEN @FirstName = FirstName AND @LastName = LastName AND @Number = Number
            THEN @row_number + 1
            ELSE 1
        END AS num,
        @FirstName := FirstName as FirstName,
        @LastName := LastName as LastName,
        @Number := Number as Number,
        Status
    FROM
        t1
    ORDER BY 
        FirstName,
        lastName,
        Number,
        CASE 
            WHEN STATUS = 'King' THEN '1'
            WHEN STATUS = 'Queen' THEN '2'
            WHEN STATUS = 'Jack' THEN '3'
        END
    ) as ttt
WHERE num = 1;
```